# Select text event in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, touch

On android browser, when we touch and hold the text the text got selected and   options like copy,cut,paste are shown. But when we fire select text event using javascript, the text got selected but copy,cut,paste options are not shown. Why?

The code for text select:

```
<body onload = "selecText();">
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function selecText()
         {
        document.getElementById("textareaid").value ="selected text area";
              document.getElementById("textareaid").focus();
              document.getElementById("textareaid").select();
          }
      </script>
      <textarea value="abdc"   id="textareaid"   ></textarea>
 </body>
```

Comment: Is it possible that the options get shown on some other event if there is text selected, such as touchend? I don't know this, it's just an idea.

Comment: paste the part of your code in which you are firing to select text by javascript

Comment: You should edit your original post instead of putting code in a comment.